# Rstudio- Removing Dependencies rJava and xlsx

Tags: r, excel, dependencies, xlsx, rjava

I hope someone can help me. We needed to install "xlsx" but it didn't work on my MacBook Air (10.15.7). So I tried to found a solution on websites and installed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLkIO.png) this "install.packages("rJava", repos="http://rforge.net", type="source")"
I don't know how but I created a dependency and want to remove it. Every time I delete "rJava" in the packages it still shows up when I write "install.packages("xlsx") "library(xlsx)". My question is how do I remove the dependencies?

This is my outcome:

***> install.packages("xlsx")
also installing the dependency ‘rJava’***

*> library(xlsx)
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "(null)".
No Java runtime present, try --request to install.
Fehler: package or namespace load failed for ‘xlsx’:
.onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'rJava' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
Aufruf: fun(libname, pkgname)
Fehler: JVM could not be found
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen:
1: In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
Ausführung von Kommando '/usr/libexec/java_home' ergab Status 1
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
Cannot find JVM library 'NA/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
Install Java and/or check JAVA_HOME (if in doubt, do NOT set it, it will be detected)*

How do I remove the dependency? THANK U SO MUCH

Comment: The `xlsx` package depends on the `rJava` package. You cannot change that. There are other packages for reading/writing XLSX files: `readxl`, `writexl`, `openxlsx`. These ones do not depend on `rJava`.

Comment: Thx u so much! have a good day!

Comment: In case you are still looking for `rJava` take a look here: https://www.owsiak.org/r-java-11-and-making-sure-you-can-load-rjava/